# Distinguish button_press_event from drag and zoom clicks in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a simple code that shows two subplots, and lets the user left click on the second subplot while recording the `x,y` coordinates of those clicks.

The problem is that clicks to select a region to zoom and to drag the subplot are also identified as left clicks.

Is there a way to distinguish and filter out these left clicks?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def onclick(event, ax):
    # Only clicks inside this axis are valid.
    if event.inaxes == ax:
        if event.button == 1:
            print(event.xdata, event.ydata)
            # Draw the click just made
            ax.scatter(event.xdata, event.ydata)
            ax.figure.canvas.draw()
        elif event.button == 2:
            # Do nothing
            print("scroll click")
        elif event.button == 3:
            # Do nothing
            print("right click")
        else:
            pass


fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
# Plot some random scatter data
ax2.scatter(np.random.uniform(0., 10., 10), np.random.uniform(0., 10., 10))

fig.canvas.mpl_connect(
    'button_press_event', lambda event: onclick(event, ax2))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may check if the mouse button is released after the mouse has previously been moved. Since for zooming and panning, this would be the case you may call the function to draw a new point only when no previous movement has happened.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Click():
    def __init__(self, ax, func, button=1):
        self.ax=ax
        self.func=func
        self.button=button
        self.press=False
        self.move = False
        self.c1=self.ax.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.onpress)
        self.c2=self.ax.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('button_release_event', self.onrelease)
        self.c3=self.ax.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', self.onmove)

    def onclick(self,event):
        if event.inaxes == self.ax:
            if event.button == self.button:
                self.func(event, self.ax)
    def onpress(self,event):
        self.press=True
    def onmove(self,event):
        if self.press:
            self.move=True
    def onrelease(self,event):
        if self.press and not self.move:
            self.onclick(event)
        self.press=False; self.move=False


def func(event, ax):
    print(event.xdata, event.ydata)
    ax.scatter(event.xdata, event.ydata)
    ax.figure.canvas.draw()

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
# Plot some random scatter data
ax2.scatter(np.random.uniform(0., 10., 10), np.random.uniform(0., 10., 10))
click = Click(ax2, func, button=1)
plt.show()
```

Comment: In my experience, this works very well when using a trackpad. However, in practice, when I run my tkinter app with a sensitive mouse, it is difficult to click without also incorporating a subtle motion prior to releasing the button. Any suggestions?

Comment: @brandontober Consider the other answer to this question?

Comment: Yes I could do that. However, I liked your solution and was trying to find a way to make it work.

Comment: @brandontober You can surely incorporate the idea of a maximum time condition into this answer if you want.

Answer (score 7):

I realize that this is an old question, but I just had the same problem and I think I found a neat solution; however it currently works only for the Qt backend (similar solutions might exist for other backends too). The idea is that matplotlib changes the cursor shape while zooming or panning, so you can check for that. This is the adapted code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('qt5agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def onclick(event, ax):
    # Only clicks inside this axis are valid.
    try: # use try/except in case we are not using Qt backend
        zooming_panning = ( fig.canvas.cursor().shape() != 0 ) # 0 is the arrow, which means we are not zooming or panning.
    except:
        zooming_panning = False
    if zooming_panning: 
        print("Zooming or panning")
        return
    if event.inaxes == ax:
        if event.button == 1:
            print(event.xdata, event.ydata)
            # Draw the click just made
            ax.scatter(event.xdata, event.ydata)
            ax.figure.canvas.draw()
        elif event.button == 2:
            # Do nothing
            print("scroll click")
        elif event.button == 3:
            # Do nothing
            print("right click")
        else:
            pass


fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
# Plot some random scatter data
ax2.scatter(np.random.uniform(0., 10., 10), np.random.uniform(0., 10., 10))

fig.canvas.mpl_connect(
    'button_press_event', lambda event: onclick(event, ax2))
plt.show()
```

Comment: This worked like a charm.  So easy for my Qt4 implementation.

Comment: With tk backend, I am currently testing toolbar.mode (returns True if pan/zoom button is selected, False if not), not sure if its supported though,

Answer (score 4):

One way to distinguish between clicks and dragging/zooming (be it right click or left click) would be to measure the time between the button press and the button release and then carry out the actions on the button release, not the button press.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

MAX_CLICK_LENGTH = 0.1 # in seconds; anything longer is a drag motion

def onclick(event, ax):
    ax.time_onclick = time.time()

def onrelease(event, ax):
    # Only clicks inside this axis are valid.
    if event.inaxes == ax:
        if event.button == 1 and ((time.time() - ax.time_onclick) < MAX_CLICK_LENGTH):
            print(event.xdata, event.ydata)
            # Draw the click just made
            ax.scatter(event.xdata, event.ydata)
            ax.figure.canvas.draw()
        elif event.button == 2:
            print("scroll click")
        elif event.button == 3:
            print("right click")
        else:
            pass


fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
# Plot some random scatter data
ax2.scatter(np.random.uniform(0., 10., 10), np.random.uniform(0., 10., 10))

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', lambda event: onclick(event, ax2))
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_release_event', lambda event: onrelease(event, ax2))
plt.show()
```

Comment: I'm selecting this answer because it looks a bit simpler to implement. Thank you both!

Comment: The method by @ImportanceOfBeingErnest is a lot more elegant. Mine is a hack that works. I think you should reconsider. Also, he gave you a whole class that you just need to drop into your code and it will do the thing (whatever `func` ends up doing). There is nothing left for you to implement.

Comment: I agree with you, I just prefer your "hack" because it does not disrupt my existing function at all. If you think that answer deserves to be accepted, I'll change it. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

My answe would not work for the all backends, however, it works in the jupyter notebook backend **nbAgg**, similar to @Rincewind answer

```py
%matplotlib notebook
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import ipywidgets as wdg 

def onclick(event, ax):
    # Only clicks inside this axis are valid.
    if event.inaxes != ax:
        return
    
    # Not adding points when zooming or paning
    ptr_type = str(fig.canvas.toolbar.cursor)
    pick = 'Cursors.POINTER'
    if ptr_type != pick:
        return
    
    if event.button == 1:
        print(event.xdata, event.ydata)
        # Draw the click just made
        ax.scatter(event.xdata, event.ydata)
        ax.figure.canvas.draw()
    elif event.button == 2:
        # Do nothing
        print("scroll click")
    elif event.button == 3:
        # Do nothing
        print("right click")
    else:
        pass


fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
# Plot some random scatter data
ax2.scatter(np.random.uniform(0., 10., 10), np.random.uniform(0., 10., 10))

ka = fig.canvas.mpl_connect(
    'button_press_event', lambda event: onclick(event, ax2))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for a mayplotlib widget lock (when a widget button is pressed). If it is the case, for example when panning/zooming, it returns True, and you can return from the event handler function using:

```
def onclick(event, ax):    
    if self.fig.canvas.widgetlock.locked():
        return
    #put handling of non-panning/zooming events here
```