# Distinguish button_press_event from matplotlib zoom and pan

Tags: python, user-interface, matplotlib, tkinter

This is an extension of the question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48446351/distinguish-button-press-event-from-drag-and-zoom-clicks-in-matplotlib). I was not allowed to comment there.

@ImportanceOfBeingErnest provided an excellent answer to distinguish matplotlib button_press_events from zoom and pan clicks by connecting the motion_notify_event. In my experience, this works very well when using a trackpad. However, in practice, when I run my tkinter app with a sensitive mouse, it is difficult to click without also incorporating a subtle motion prior to releasing the button.

Any suggestions? I was considering setting a flag based on the time between the button_press_event and the button_release_event.

Comment: My answer in that thread uses time as a distinguishing factor. However, I do think that using motion as the distinguishing factor (as @ImportanceOfBeingErnest does) is the better way to go as it is more directly linked to the action of zooming/panning (somebody might just be a really slow clicker and then using a time differential won't work for them). So instead of using the in-built motion_notify_event (that will kick in if there is any motion), you will need to additionally check if the mouse has moved a significant distance between button press and release.

Comment: Good point @PaulBrodersen. I ended up settling on the simply time between click and release method you had initially suggested. This works well enough for my application. Some of my clicks could be very close together so considering the distance between these events might introduce too much bias.